# unable to import Javascript test results to sonar qube

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I have used this properties and report are in XML format`JavaScript unit results are not importing to sonar dash board.

```
project.home=..\\..\\PeriodDataFrontEnd
bevo-web-module.sonar.javascript.jstestdriver.reportsPath=.
bevo-web-module.sonar.projectBaseDir=.\\bevo-web\\src`

Sensor JavaScriptSquidSensor done: 493293 ms
10:45:51.310 INFO  - Sensor JsTestDriverSensor...
10:45:51.311 INFO  - Parsing Unit Test run results in Surefire format from folder D:\workspace\PeriodDataFrontEnd\bevo-web\src\.
10:45:51.455 WARN  - Test result will not be saved for test class "0.2403 (Windows 7 0.0.0).Given the container controller", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "0\2403 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\Given the container controller.js"
10:45:51.576 WARN  - Test result will not be saved for test class "0.2403 (Windows 7 0.0.0).Given the container nav controller", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "0\2403 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\Given the container nav controller.js"
10:45:51.688 WARN  - Test result will not be saved for test class "0.2403 (Windows 7 0.0.0).Given the browser has received JSON from the server when converting the JSON to a Page instance", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "0\2403 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\Given the browser has received JSON from the server when converting the JSON to a Page instance.js"
10:45:51.805 WARN  - Test result will not be saved for test class "0.2403 (Windows 7 0.0.0).Given the page controller", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "0\2403 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\Given the page controller.js"
```

Enter code here.

Comment: What code is producing this error?

Answer (score 0):

From the information given in the log we can deduce that the XML report you provide does not follow the format supported by the JavaScript Plugin: `Test result will not be saved for test class "0.2403 (Windows 7 0.0.0).Given the container controller", because SonarQube associated resource has not been found using file name: "0\2403 (Windows 7 0\0\0)\Given the container controller.js"`

Some explanations:

- in order to associate test execution information to a test file the JavaScript plugin needs to have a path to the test file. The plugin retrieves this information from the xml test report and it is supporting only js-test-driver xml format.
- From the log you provided we can clearly see that where the plugin was expecting a file path it found something else that cannot be used to retrieve the test file.

For more details please refer to this documentation page, hoping that it is clear enough: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Unit+Test+results+import

Comment: If i Give Exact Test Result path I am getting This error:   Parsing Unit Test run results in Surefire format from folder D:\workspace\PeriodDataFrontEnd\bevo-web\src\test-results.xml
11:12:44.889 WARN  - Reports path not found: D:\workspace\PeriodDataFrontEnd\bevo-web\src\test-results.xml               
11:12:44.889 WARN  - No Unit Test information will be saved, because no Unit Test report has been found in the given directory: {}D:\workspace\PeriodDataFrontEnd\bevo-web\src\test-results.xml

Comment: i want to know is there any different between junit XML test result format and jstest driver XML test result format

Comment: @lakshman as the log indicates and the property description, a path to the **directory** containing the xml reports  is expected not the path to an xml **file**

Comment: if i give path to the dirctory containg xml file also it showing same error:  Parsing Unit Test run results in Surefire format from folder D:\workspace\PeriodDataFrontEnd\bevo-web\src
12:49:33.824 WARN  - No Unit Test information will be saved, because no Unit Test report has been found in the given directory: {}D:\workspace\PeriodDataFrontEnd\bevo-web\src